# How to extract frames with ffmpeg? What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract frames from an MP4 using FFMpeg.

When I run:

```
ffmpeg -i aaa.mp4 -r 10 extraced%03d.png
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Could not open file extracted"path-were-ffmpeg.exe-is/a.bat3d.png"

av_interleaved_write_frame<>: input/output error
```

Why did I get that filename? I'm using a batch script to execute this, is that wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this: `ffmpeg -i aaa.mp4 -r 1/1 $extracted%03d.png`

Comment: what is the `fps` (frame rate) of your video? Try to use `jpg` or `bmp` instead of `png`

Comment: @Ĭsααctիεβöss: I try everything you have told me and none of that work. I know now why, it can't be done from a batch script, only from cmd. I use the command line that I post and it works from there. Thanks and cheers.

Comment: Please post a detailed answer below. Right now, it's a little unclear how the script looks like and what the exact errors are (complete log missing)